# Next previous article based on order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've got a list of all my articles, ordered by client name.

articles_controller.rb - index

```
@articles = Article.order('client')
```

In my show page, how do I get the next and previous article in that order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the article for the show action, you could use 'index' to get the position of this article in the Array returned by 'Article.order('client').all'

Somehow like this:

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@article_list = Article.order(:client).all
index = @article_list.index(@article)
```

Based on this you can calculate the previous and next article simple enough. Not sure if this is the smartest solution, but it should work.

Comment: That looks good - thanks.  I guess in your third line you mean `index = @article_list.index(@article)`?

Comment: yes, sure. sorry typo. corrected :) and could be @index if you want to use this in your view

Answer (score 0):

have two scopes in your model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :order_by_id, lambda {
    {:order => "id desc"} 
  }

  scope :order_by_client, lambda {|client_id|
    {:order => "client_id desc"} 
  }

end
```

and

```
@articles = Article.order_by_client(1).order_by_id
```

with validations you could do something like

*next article* (say the current article index is 1)

@articles(current_index + 1) unless @articles(current_index + 1).nil?

*previous article* (say the current article index is 2)

@articles(current_index - 1) unless @articles(current_index - 1).nil?

** havent tried the code but should work